# ASP.net jquery add +1 day in 2nd calendar datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#arrival").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#departure").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
        }
    });

    $("#departure").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#arrival").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
        }
    });
});
```

i have Arrival Date and Departure Date. In departure date, i want to add +1 more day.
example:

i choose 2/20/2013 in ARRIVAL then in DEPARTURE calendar the minimum date i should pick
will be 2/21/2013 NOT 2/20/2013. HELP ME PLEASE! i am newbie in asp and jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just add one day then ?

```
$("#arrival").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()+1);
        $("#departure").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate)
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsu5c/7/)

Comment: its working but the YEAR in departure calendar jumps to 2068. why??

Comment: @JakerusselPalma - It does'nt do that for me. I did change it a bit, so try the link again?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse.

```
    $("#arrival").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#departure").datepicker("option", "minDate", Date.parse(selected)+1)
        }
    });

    $("#departure").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#arrival").datepicker("option", "maxDate", Date.parse(selected)-1)
        }
    });
```

Comment: not working. the departure calendar shows the current date :(